# Child activity menu not working with TabActivity

Tags: android, menu

I have 1 TabActivity(MainActivity)and 3 activities for 3 tab.(A, B, C Activities),
Now i override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) methods in MainActivity.

When i select menu the MainActivity's onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) is called(its ok).
but onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method which override in other child activities(A, B, C) not called.

How can i called the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method of other child activities(A, B, C) when user select MainActivity's onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)?

i find solution for this problem from last 3 days. i read most of answer related to this issue but no solution found for this problem.
please please help me.
see image which describe my problem.

[image]

Comment: sorry for bad English

Comment: `TabActivity`, and activities-in-tabs, has been deprecated for **nearly three years**. Please feel free to use a supported tab solution: `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, action bar tabs, `FragmentTabHost`, or a `TabHost` with views for tabs.

Comment: i recently search about ViewPager(http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/), it amazing thanks "CommonsWare",

Comment: can i use overflow(three dot)menu in it?

Comment: The overflow is part of the action bar. It is not directly tied to any tab solution. You can use the action bar, with the overflow, with a `ViewPager`.

Comment: thank you thank you,  CommonsWare, you solved my biggest problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call getCurrentActivity().onOptionsItemSelected(item) in your TabActivity.onOptionsItemSelected

But please note this solution, don't call super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) in your child activities. Because the super onOptionsItemSelected will call TabActivity's onOptionsItemSelected again. it will cause a call loop.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return getCurrentActivity().onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

A, B, C Activities

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ...
    return true;
}
```